# Having issue with click function for <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tablerow

**HTML**

```
<tr url="domain.com">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" method="post" value="" class="checkbox" />  </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$("tr").not('.checkbox').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("url");

});
```

Want to disable click function inside clickbox, but code above doesn't work: it redirects even when I click in checkbox. Where  did I go wrong?

Comment: I advice you use the `data-` syntax. `<tr data-custom-url="http://domain.com">` and access it as `$("selector").data("custom-url");`. By the way, if I'm not mistaken you must also indicate the protocol of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stop event propogation on checkbox like below,

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Fixed the typo.

Comment: @sks but I selected as answer. First answer with stopPropagation(); suggestion was his. Bravo. Works!

Comment: I am not able to remove the dv even though you edited it, edit it again I will try.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("tr").not('.checkbox')
```

This code will match all `tr` elements which do not have a class of `checkbox`.  As you can see, your `tr` does not have that class, so this `tr` will match.

There are 2 basic approaches to doing what you are trying to do.  You can either check in the function what the original clicked element was and don't redirect if it was a checkbox.  Or, you can add a click handler to the checkbox and call `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
$("tr .checkbox").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a separate handler that stopps propagation.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("url");
})
  .find(".checkbox").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop the event propagation on checkbox click. Try this.

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

And change your code to

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("url");

});
```

Alternatively you can check for target and act accordingly. Try this.

```
$("tr").click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is(':checkbox')){
       window.location = $(this).attr("url");
    }
});
```